# Android SQLite datatabse: Do I just need to create a DBHelper object and instantiate it to create a database?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, file

New to SQLite. Just one simple question, given my DBHelper.java, do I just need to add this code:

```
DBHelper dbhelper= new DBHelper(MainActivity.this);
```

in my MainActivity.java to create my letterhunter.db?

No need to call the onCreate method?

This is my DBHelper.java

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String TAG = "WordDatabase";

//Table names;
public static final String T_NAME = "WORDS";
public static final String T2_NAME = "SCORE";

//Column names
public static final String C_WKEYS = "Word Keys";
public static final String C_WORDS = "List of Words";
public static final String C_SKEYS = "Score Keys";
public static final String C_SCORE = "Score";

//Database info
public static final String DB_NAME = "letterhunter.db";
public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

private final Context context;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    this.context = context;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String sql = String.format("create table %s " + "(%s integer primary key autoincrement, %s text)" , T_NAME, C_WKEYS, C_WORDS);
    Log.d (TAG , "create sql "+sql);    
    db.execSQL(sql);
    fillDB();
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("drop if exists " + T_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

private void fillDB(){
    new Thread(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                loadWords();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }).start();

}

//Get the listed words in raw/words.txt and insert to the database  
private void loadWords() throws IOException{
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    InputStream is = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.words);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));      

        String word;
        try {
            while((word=br.readLine()) != null){
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(C_WORDS, word);

                db.insert(T_NAME, null, values);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    br.close();
    is.close(); 
}   

}
```

PS. My logcat is running nonstop when I add the above code in my MainActivity, and cannot seem to find the log.d I put inside the onCreate button.

Comment: `No need to call the onCreate method?` No. It's called by the DBHelper constructor.

Comment: `DBHelper dbhelper= new DBHelper(ManAcitivty.this);` **MainAcitivity**? `in my MainActitivyt.java to create` **MainActitivyt**? I guess these are typos...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I just need to create a DBHelper object and instantiate it to create a database?

Instantiate the helper and call `getWritableDatabase()` on it to create the database.

> No need to call the onCreate method?

It gets called by the framework when `getWritableDatabase()` is called for the first time and the database file did not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I normally add the following method to my DB helper class

```
private SQLiteDatabase db;
...

public void init() {
    if (db == null) {
        db = getWritableDatabase();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just need to instantiate it and pass the context as argument and your onCreate or onUpgrade method whichever is necessary will be called explicitly wherever you call `getWritableDatabase()`.

`PS. My logcat is running nonstop when I add the above code in my MainActivity, and cannot seem to find the log.d I put inside the onCreate button.`

I would like to suggest you a sollution for this,
any of your Log.i/d/e/v can easily be traced in logcat by the following steps.

`Log.i/e/v/d` takes two arguments `TAG` and `String` where `String` is the message that could be displayed in logcat and `TAG` is tag by which this message could be traced. In your logcat view in eclipse you will find `+` as displayed in the image below;

[image]

click on this icon, It will show you the following window in this you just need to enter whatever filter name you want and need to enter the `TAG` in by Log Tag field for example I have entered `Setu` You can also add more details if you want to trace particular log. In the last field `by Log level` You can choose as appropriately as you wrote in your code e.g. info for `Log.i` error for Log.e and so on; [image]

now as per this example whenever in my code I will have following Logs i will be able to trace them in saved filters tab by the filter name specified by me. e.g.

```
Log.i("Setu","This is just and example");
Log.e("Setu","Error occurred here");
Log.d("Setu","Bla... Bla.. Bla...");
```

You can create as many filters as you want and trace your log.